# How can I refer to the nth area in a non-contigious Excel range?

Tags: excel, areas, vba

Assume I selected the range `A1:B2,C3:C5`.
[image: Excel screenshot showing selection of a non-contiguous range]

Using VBA, I can loop through each area like this:

```
Dim iArea As Range
For Each iArea In Application.Selection.Areas
    Debug.Print iArea.Address
Next iArea
```

I am able to return each range's address, in this case `$A$1:$B$2` and `$C$3:$C$5`.

How can I refer to the 2nd area in a range, or better yet, the nth area?  I can refer to the nth cell in a range using `Range.Cells(cellNumberToReturn)`.  Is something similar for ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use indexer:

```
Sub F()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:B2,D3:E5")
    Set rngArea = rng.Areas(2)
    MsgBox rngArea.Address(0, 0) 'Shows D3:E5

End Sub
```